# How do I get enemy across an obstacle

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a tank game in unity. I have made the enemy tank follow the player, turn towards the player and shoot. But if an obstacle is in between the enemy and the player the enemy just shoots at the obstacle. How do I make the enemy get across the obstacle and then shoot the player

Comment: Unity's *NavMesh* is the solution for your problem. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHV1ymlw-P8) you can check it out

Answer (score 0):

yes a possible solution is to use Unity´s Navmesh System. 
With this System you can make the tank navigate around the obstacle towards the player.
If you only want to shoot whenever your tank "sees" the Player you could make a Raycast that fires into the direction of your Projectile. If the collision object is the Player you can enable shooting.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html
https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/raycasting

Ps.: Especially have a look at NavMesh Obstacles.